# Call from Java to run an executable as a different user

Tags: java, powershell

Question:
I have to call an exe file passing 2 string arguments. The call has to get executed as a different user

I referred few of the links that I got from hints. Couple of them were using powershell, few were using runas examples and so on.
But with powershell also, I am not sure if I will face the issue of "cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system".
Just because of this reason, I want to try something authentic.

Tried following approaches

1. Trying to do it through a call with RunAs command is making my life difficult. (called a batch file with RunAs command passing a separate pass.txt or savecred). savecred was ruled out by most people. Other one did not work as expected.
2. Powershell, has issues wherein, I always get a userid/password popup, even though I run through a Java file.

I also get an error in the command prompt as here below
 + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodExcept
ion
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.Power
Shell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

(Sample code attached below)

```
public class SamplePS {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    String command = "powershell C:\\Users\\Ramu\\Project\\SampleFile.ps1";
    //String cmds[] = {"C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe", "\\c", "SampleFile.ps"};
    System.out.println("1");
    Process proc = runtime.exec(command);
    InputStream is = proc.getErrorStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    System.out.println("2");

}
```

}

My ps1 file is as here below

```
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential <<domain>>\<<user id>>, <<password>>
start-process cmd.exe -arg "/k dir" -Credential $credential
```

What is the best way to handle this scenario?
Please suggest! I am not sure what approach to take.
Powershell or Perl or any other scripting.
Whatever it be, I have to make a call from Java file.

Please suggest!
Note: For time being, I dont mind the password being sent as a plain text.
The exe file is in Windows machine

Thanks!
Ram

Comment: The problem is in your PowerShell script: You can't pass a plain-text password directly to a `System.Management.Automation.PSCredential` (`[pscredential]`) constructor - it must be a `[securestring]` instance. To construct such an instance from a plain-text string - which is ill-advised, use `ConvertTo-SecureString 'plain-text password' -AsPlainText -Force`